# Typescript definitions, ES6 class, and constructors

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I have a TypeScript project in which I'd like to use `libmarkov` from npm. It provides an ES6-importable class called Generator. You use it via `new Generator('some text')`.

In my local project, I created a file `typedefs/libmarkov.d.ts`:

```
export class Generator {
    constructor(text: string);
    generate(depth: number);
}
```

I use `typings` to install it: `typings install --save file:./typedefs/libmarkov.d.ts`

However, this: `let generator = new Generator('Foo Bar Baz');`

...generates this compiler error:

```
Error:(5, 21) TS2351: Cannot use 'new' with an expression whose type lacks a call or construct signature.
```

I could change my constructor: `constructor(text: string) {};`

...but this gives:

```
Error:(2, 31) TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts.
```

If it matters, I'm targeting TS 2.0.

Comment: Replace `export` with `declare`

Comment: If I replace with `export`, I still get the error about `new`. If I then add `{}` at the end of `constructor`, I still get the `new` error, but also get `Error:(2, 31) TS1183: An implementation cannot be declared in ambient contexts`.

Answer (score 7):

Since this is a js library, I suspect you load it with something like

```
import {Generator} from "libmarkov"
```

In which case your external module definition must look like

```
declare module "libmarkov" {

    export class Generator {
        constructor(text: string);
        generate(depth: number);
    }
}
```

**EDIT**
The definition is wrong; libmarkov seems to use [a default export](https://github.com/jaxgeller/libmarkov/blob/master/javascript/bin/index.js).

```
declare module "libmarkov" {

    export default class Generator {
        constructor(text: string);
        generate(depth: number);
    }
}
```

And the import would be

```
import Generator from 'libmarkov'
```

Comment: Yes, that's what results under `typings/modules/libmarkov/index.d.ts` after I run `typings`. I guess `typings` wraps my `libmarkov.d.ts` in the `declare module`. However, I'm still stuck with the error about `new`.

Comment: The definition is wrong; libmarkov seems to use a default export. See edit above

Comment: Here's a question that might help me understand ambient/global etc. For this scenario (external ES6 module in `node_modules`), after I run my `typings`, should `libmarkov` wind up in `typings/globals` or `typings/modules`? Meaning, do I do `typings --global --save` or just `typings -save`?

Comment: Hmmm, not quite there. The commonjs that TypeScript generates says (to paraphrase) `var libmarkov_1 = require('libmarkov'); new libmarkov_1.default('Foo Bar zBaz');`. But `.default` is undefined.

Comment: Try `const Generator = require('libmarkov'); new Generator('Foo Bar')`

Comment: Yes, I ultimately installed dt~require and went that route.